# Assign string value to multiple values in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to assign an atheist string value or get a new list column of consist elements.

```
df['non-Religion'] = np.where(df['Religion'] == ['Marital Status', 'None', ' ','Private', 'Nope'], 1, df['Religion'])

df.loc[df['Religion'] == ['Marital Status', 'None', ' ','Private', 'Nope','Undecided', 'Religion']
```

I tried to these 2 ways but I failed could you help me?

Comment: Will you please show a sample of your dataframe?

Comment: A sample of desired result would be helpful, too.

Comment: `df["Religion"] = df['Religion'].where(df["Religion"].isin(['Marital Status', 'None', ' ','Private', 'Nope']), "Atheist")`

Comment: @not_speshal I want to do the opposite one that your codes do

Comment: So: `df["Religion"] = df['Religion'].where(~df["Religion"].isin(['Marital Status', 'None', ' ','Private', 'Nope']), "Atheist")`